# Rails datetime picker issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I'm using the bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem for datetime pickers. When I select a date, in the params it comes across in mm/dd/yyyy" format. I see this in the controller:

```
"start_date"=>"05/01/2018"
```

However, the model thinks it's dd/mm/yyyy:

```
(byebug) start_date
Fri, 05 Jan 2018
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control" 
format="mm/dd/yyyy" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text" 
value="05/01/2018" name="gig[start_date]" id="gig_start_date">
```

How do I make the dates consistent?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

Through js or in rails controller,

1. rails way

First convert params string into Date, and Then using strftime function convert it into particular format.

```
def date_conversion(params_date)
  d = params_date.to_date
  converted_date = d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #use any format here
end
```

You can use `Date.strptime(params_date, "%d/%m/%Y")` method also

2. In js,

   var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();

Hope this will work

Comment: The rails way required a slight tweak because "mm/dd/yyyy" conversions don't work. See here: https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date#1309-Month-first-date-string-no-longer-parses-correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work:

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
</script>
```